# Should I be worried about being left out of the loop?

Tags: communication, meetings

I'm currently working on a new project that will get integrated into 3 more projects (of which all I'm partially responsible for). As of late, I've been hearing of certain demos and meetings that are happening that I'm not being scheduled to attend, where previously I was invited to them/similar ones. One was a weekly status meeting that stopped happening, another was a status meeting for a project I'm partially responsible for, and recently a co-worker was preparing a demo for one project I didn't know was happening, which I should have been prioritizing my work towards (my boss said I should but I wasn't aware of the urgency). A lot of the integration for the demo ended up being done by him, whereby he also seemed to have copied a lot of my code/rewrote quite a bit of stuff to get the final product (feel like I could have been more of a help?). I also find out about this mostly just from casual coworker conversation.

I'm still actively scheduled to work on these projects with hours forecasted accordingly for now but I feel out of the loop. Alot of the communication I had with my boss and co-workers now requires me to reach out versus hearing about it in a status meeting or having someone tell me directly.

Should I be worried about the lack of information sharing that I've been used to? Do I just need to accept that I will  have to be more proactive from now on? Should I talk to my boss about this, and what might I say? This is also my first job out of college, and, while I was given a very good raise at the start of the year, I feel like my performance isn't that great and I have trouble keeping up with the speed of my coworkers (or perhaps I'm just being too hard on myself).

Comment: Have you talked to your manager about this? Maybe he/she has another perspective and has a reason for not inviting you for those meetings.

Comment: Your 'co-workers'; the people still having the meetings, catch-ups, demos etc., where are they on the chain of command compared to you? (You said it's your first job out of college but I wouldn't want to just assume where you are.)

Comment: Focus on your own contributions and performance.  If you think that a coworker is "taking over" work you should have been doing, that might be a sign you're not moving quickly enough, or the output isn't solid enough.  Or it might be a sign that your coworker had more time available, or that he's not a great at delegating. Ask your manager, and specifically ask what if anything you can improve on.  The "loop" will take care of itself.

Answer (score 2):

Many people want to be one rung higher, in the important meetings & consulted about change. But if everyone was allowed to be then the company would grind to a halt.

If you want to progress in a company it is rarely a straight line progression - there can be periods where you need to tough it out when you seem to be stagnating with a less interest from senior management & other times when you seem to be getting big pay rises & good attention from senior management.

I would suggest that your management gave you plenty of leeway in your early time in the company but as they have got used to your strengths & weaknesses the company has settled into a rhythm that involves you in fewer meetings & taking up less of your colleagues time, for the time being.

I would treat this as a bump in the road, reach out to your colleagues & make sure that you are aligned to the company needs. Reach out to your manager & make sure that you are travelling in the right direction. If you are committed to the company then simply do the job in front of you.